# Base CSS styles not showing up on staging env

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I got react-select v2 working perfectly on my local environment. However, when I push it to a staging environment, it no longer shows the base styles. In my local env, I can see the styles are being added via data-emotion. On staging, there is one empty style tag with the data-emotion attribute.

It seems like maybe a webpack issue, as I have different ones for dev and staging, yet everything I tried hasn't worked so far. Anyone else come across this? I feel like I must be missing something super simple.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @werbelow, can you provide some example of your environments ? Thank you

Comment: @werbelow any luck with this? I have the same problem and can't seem to figure out what it is. Been trying to figure it out for hours.